# Setup error Android Studio In MAC

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have installed android studio on my MAC but when I try to open it for the first time when go through the SetUp I am getting the following error.

[image]

I have selected the option to give permission to download apps from anywhere (Allow apps to download from anywhere)

I am sure the internet connection is perfect. That is not the case.

Does anyone know what the reason for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to download the Android SDK and failing. You can [install the standalone tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) and tell Android Studio where the SDK is by opening it up to the Welcome screen and navigating to Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure. Just don't put the SDK in the .app directory of Android Studio.

It's been a while since I've installed AS, but if it's trying to download the SDK before the welcome screen appears, there probably is an option to decline the download and use an already-existing SDK.